# After removing AVG 2015 Windows Defender will not start

Tags: windows-defender, avg-antivirus

System: Windows Pro 8.1

After removal of AVG 2015, Windows Defender fails to start.

When attempting to start Windows Defender via the UI

[image]

It fails to start with error 0x8007139f

[image]

When attempting to start the service

[image]

It fails with error :

> Error 577: The Windows Defender Service service failed to start due to the following error: 
>   Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.

[image]

Does anyone know how to repair Windows Defender or otherwise get the service running again?

Comment: Try system file checker - `sfc /scannow` ... More info at: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/wiki/protect_defender-protect_start/problems-starting-windows-defender-in-windows/808253bb-db89-4db9-a4e5-1c91a86489e9

Comment: Did you use AVG's removal tool to remove the product  installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the fix to the issue. I had tried multiple registry edits suggested on many other forums. I had tried the System File Checker but that had always reported everything was ok. I had even re-installed AVG and used their removal tool. Still nothing got Defender re-enabled.

What actually ended up leading me to a fix was someone pointed me to an article where a user had uninstalled AVG and wasn't able to run Defender just like myself. For them the fix ended up being to remove SpyBot's active service. That seemed pretty reasonable but I didn't have SpyBot installed. It did get me to think of other programs that had a security focus though. I had Comodo's personal firewall installed. Comodo does offer other services such as AV in their suite of products but I was running just the firewall portion. Still, I figured it was worth a try. I uninstalled Comodo's software and that did the trick. I even re-installed the Comodo firewall and Defender is still running just fine.

So, the final fix was, uninstalling then reinstalling Comodo's firewall product.

Answer (score 0):

I had spent a long time looking at various group policies/registry keys, in an attempt to enable the windows defender service, always getting Error 577. I switched off AVG, BUT DIDN'T REMOVE IT (duh!) as I couldn't believe that, if it was disabling Windows Defender, it wouldn't have done such a bad job. Windows Update STILL (repeatedly) attempted to download definition updates. Having removed AVG completely, I was very happy (but annoyed with myself) that the Windows Defender process ran and updated definitions correctly. My PC ALSO SEEMS FASTER without AVG, software that I have trusted for a long time. I will find it difficult to put my faith in MS security, but will do so until the next virus disaster. ;)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)